# will reading mongodb collection from pyspark, makes mongodb slow or will result in write lock and crashes mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, replication

this is the way I read data from replication mongodb .

```
def read_col(self, collection_name, spark):
    return spark.read.format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource') \
        .option('uri', '{}/{}.{}?authSource={}'
                .format(self.mongo_url, self.mongo_db, collection_name, self.auth_source)) \
        .option('sampleSize', 50000)\
        .load()
```

I read a large db for data processing with pyspark. But the backend team says because Im reading the data from mongodb at that time write lock occurs at replication mongodb and primary mongodb is not able to sync with replication and finally mongodb crashes, but write has more priority that read isn't it? 
Can anyone suggest there opinion on this matter

Comment: The secondary node requires a global exclusive write lock to apply replicated operations from the primary.  While something is actively reading, the exclusive lock cannot be taken.  Note that "actively reading" is usually intermittent for long running queries.  If you can upgrade to MongoDB 4.0, they introduced non-blocking secondary reads that do not have that issue.

Comment: Thanks joe for your opinion. Currently they are using Mongodb 4.2 , And Im quite new to MongoDB, so can you tell me how to implement this "non-blocking secondary reads" like do we have to edit the mongoquery or is it a by default feature.

Comment: That feature should be available by default.  There was a [blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/secondary-reads-mongodb-40) about it when it came out.